# How to retrieve second level data from Multidimensional array in Angular 7 Ionic 5

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and I am trying my hand at multidimensional arrays. I am successfully retrieving and displaying the 1st level data in my json multidimensional array. However, I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for retrieving the data from the second layer of the array. I have looked at quite a few solutions for multidimensional arrays but none seem to fit what I am trying to do. I created a service component and added my code to it. This is what I have so far:

Condensed array definition (the actual array has many more elements and fields):

```
private _fundraisers: Fundraiser[] = [
    {
      fundId: 'f1',
      fundTitle: 'The happy fund',
      items: [
        {
          itemId: '66', 
          itemTitle: 'sixTea6'
        },
        {
          itemId: '88', 
          itemTitle: 'eighTea8',
        }]
    }
  ];
```

I have the following function to retrieve an element from the top level array, using the variable fundId.

```
getFundraiser(fundId: string) {
    return {...this._fundraisers.find(fundraiser => {
      return fundraiser.fundId === fundId;
    })};
  }
```

This function returns the required element and all "items" for the fundId. Now when a user selects one of the "items", I want to return all the details only for that item. So if I am displaying the record for 'f1' and the user selects item '66', I want to pass 'f1' and '66' to a function and return the details for f1/66. This is what I have tried with no success.

```
  getFundraiserItem(fundId: string, itemId: string) {
    this._fundraisers.find(fundraiserItem => {       
      if (fundraiserItem.fundId === fundId) {
        console.log(fundraiserItem[0][fundId][0].itemId[0].itemId);
      }
    });
  }
```

Obviously I am only using console.log to test my code. So the console.log would be replaced with a return of some sort. I tried to piece this code together based on other solutions on stack overflow. But I am probably way off the mark. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this `console.log(((this._fundraisers.filter( (fund) => fund.fundId == fundId )) as any[])[0] ? ((this._fundraisers.filter( (fund) => fund.fundId == fundId )) as any[])[0].items.filter( (item:any)=> item.itemId == itemId) : []);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getFundraiserItem(fundId: string, itemId: string) {
  var fundraiser = this._fundraisers.find(fundraiser => fundraiser.fundId === fundId);
  var item = fundraiser.items.find(item => item.itemId === itemId);
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think you can do somethink like this, to get item by fundId & itemId:

```
    getFundraiserItemById(fundId: string, itemId: string): ItemModelHere | undefined {
 const relevantFundraiser: Fundraiser | undefined = this._fundraiser.find((f) => f.fundId === fundId);
if (!relevantFundraiser || !relevantFundraiser.items) {
return undefined;
}
return relevantFundraiser.items.find((item) => item.itemId === itemId);
```

}

Comment: Tested this solution as well. It works. I like the "undefined" catch logic.

Comment: Yes, this one handles `not found` logic. The answer above can throw an error

Comment: Is this code "ItemModelHere | undefined" required in order for the not found logic to work?

Comment: No. It's just typing for return value of the function